# Is there any connector for Rally of Testlink?

Tags: rally, testlink

I really want to import all the test cases from Testlink to Rally software. How I can do this? Is there any connector for Rally Software of Testlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rally connectors' page](https://help.rallydev.com/connectors) does not list it. If you can export test cases from Testlink to Excel you may use [Rally Excel plugin](https://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide#Importing) to import them to Rally.